# Please assist in improving my tkinter code

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my current code.
I'd like for someone to tell me how to make it easier or generally improve it
I used some rather dodgy work a rounds for problems I didn't know how to solve with my little code knowledge (for example the account number).
Oh and sorry if there's a lot of spelling/grammar mistakes I'm not natively English.

BTW I'm sorry if I posted this in the wrong place I didn't quite know where else to go to to ask.
I even tried asking my ICT teacher but he  didn't even understand what I did, so yeah didn't quite work out.

```
from cProfile import run
from distutils import command
from lib2to3.pytree import convert
import tkinter as tk
import linecache

master = tk.Tk()
master.iconbitmap("naamloos.ico")
master.title("Chat Login")

a = 0
b = 0

def error_1():
    tk.Label(master, text="Password or Username is uncorrect").grid(row=0)

def Goto_chat():
    print("1")

file = open("email.txt", "r")
x = 0
for line in file:
    if line != "\n":
        x += 1
file.close()
AN = x + 1

tk.Label(master, text="User Name").grid(row=3, column=0)
tk.Label(master, text="Email").grid(row=4, column=0)
tk.Label(master, text="Account Number").grid(row=5, column=0)

e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)
e3 = tk.Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=3, column=1)
e2.grid(row=4, column=1)
e3.grid(row=5, column=1)

def Done():
    z = e1.get()
    y = e2.get()
    x1 = e3.get()
    Eline = (linecache.getline("email.txt", int(x1)).rstrip('\n'))
    if Eline in y:
        a = 1
    Uline = (linecache.getline("user.txt", int(x1)).rstrip('\n'))
    if Uline in z:
       b = 1
    if a + b == 2:
        Goto_chat()
        #open another program
    else:
        error_1()
        
def Register_check():
    Ucheck = e1.get()
    if Ucheck in open("user.txt").read():
       tk.Label(master, text="Username taken").grid(row=1)
    else:
        Register()

def Register():
    if e2.get() == "": 
        print("0")
    else:
        Wemail = open("email.txt", "a")
        Wemail.writelines(e2.get() + "\n")
    if e1.get() == "": 
        print("0")
    else:
        Wuser = open("user.txt", "a")
        Wuser.writelines(e1.get() + "\n")
        tk.Label(master, text="Account Number: " + str(AN)).grid(row=2)

tk.Button(master, text="Login", command=Done, width=20).grid(row=6,column=0)
tk.Button(master, text="Register", command=Register_check, width=20).grid(row=6,column=1)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hey buran, can you send question link just to check ?

Comment: @buran: It doesn't belong on Code Review if it doesn't work (and it doesn't, at least not as posted).

Comment: @martineau, I don't see any question or problem statement, except _I'd like for someone to tell me **how to make it easier or generally improve it**_ I admit I didn't run it.

Comment: @buran: Yeah, that's what the title said, but sometimes you have to read the body of the question, too (or at least try to make sense if it). ;¬)

Comment: @martineau, sorry, but could you point to the part in the question you refer to. I read the body of the question before I voted and then quoted the relevant part. There is NO question or statement of problem with the code.

Comment: @buranL Sorry, you're right. I know enough about `tkinter` to determine that it wouldn't work (again, as posted) and assumed that was the "improvement" they wanted — but they never explicitly mentioned that.

Comment: @martineau, no problem. I didn't look into the code in detail, just the text. Anyway, with missing `ico` and `txt` files we cannot run it anyway.

Comment: @Dev_Xam: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev_Xam  I cheer you, your code is the best improved and it's in the best way to be, I have only found 1 improvement which I think could help you. It is at line 20, change it to the following:

```py
with open("email.txt", "r") as file:
    x = sum(line != "\n" for line in file)
AN = x + 1
```

Why ? We need to use 'with' when opening file to ensure closure, Convert for loop into call to sum(), Simplify constant sum() call